Having problem for removing package named linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 13.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 289152 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic (6.2.0-39.40) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-39-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/CyberSynchro/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux: 1: version_find_latest: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

How can I solove this problem ?

Please format your question to be human readable ;) here is how: https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

And please search for remove grub-customizer complete from Ubuntu.
